# How do I use Nokogiri to scrape text from an image tag?

Tags: ruby, xml, image, nokogiri

I need to get text from a list of image tags that are formatted like this:

```
<img src="/images/TextImage.ashx?text=Richmond" style="border-width:0px;" class="">
```

When I enter the XPath into Nokogiri, I get:

```
[#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x80513954 name="img" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x805138dc name="src" value="/images/TextImage.ashx?text=Richmond">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x805138b4 name="style" value="border-width:0px;">]>]
```

Is there any way that I can tell Nokogiri to return "Richmond"? I'm looking for a method that will return the text after a certain string. If there is not a way to get only "Richmond", how do I get it to return the value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract the `src` attribute with an xpath expression like

```
src = doc.at_xpath '//img/@src'
```

After that, you’ll need to extract the name from the attribute, probably with a regex.

For example (this may need to be more involved, depending on what formats are possible in the `src` attribute in your HTML page):

```
/\?text=(.*)/ =~ src
puts $1
```

Comment: I got this when I did that: #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x80582994 name="src" value="/Uploads/Gallery/banners NEW/Atlata.jpg">

Comment: @Guyana.Hand Yes, that’s the attribute node. You’ll need to extract the place name from it using a regex (you can use it directly with a regex as if it was a string, its `to_str` method returns the attribute value). Note that it’s in a different format to the one in your question, so your overall regex will need to be more complex than the simple one I used in my answer.

Comment: Thanks! I don't know how to use regex. Can you recommend a tutorial?